# Redirect user to another url after POST request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm working on a django app and I need to redirect user to another url after processing the POST request in views. How can I redirect? something like return redirect('user:deploy').

Help me, please!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: post the code you have. but actually you don't have to simply search and find the answer this is a repost!

Comment: Returning a redirect is *exactly* what you have to do. What happens when you try that?

Comment: I have tried answer posted below by @Ankur, it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Import redirect class
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Your code
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("user:deploy"))
```